# How to resolve the JMS publisher issue?

Tags: javascript, performance, jmeter

I am using the JMS Publisher in Jmeter and When I replay the script I am getting below error message.

> Response message: javax.naming.NamingException: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class:  [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ]

Can you please help me on this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#lets_start):

> JMeter includes the JMS API jar, but **does not include a JMS client implementation**. If you want to run JMS tests, you will need to download the appropriate jars from the JMS provider.

So you need to download an appropriate Java JMS Client libraries for your JMS provider (Active MQ, WebSphere MQ, whatever), drop them to the "lib" folder of your JMeter installation and restart JMeter to pick the jars up.

More detailed information: [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter)